# Alternative to using Control.Invoke

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

In a Visual C# / .Net application, I have to read the SerialPort, and hence I assigned it an DataReceivedEventHandler.

However, I can't of course directly change UI controls from the handler, because they live on a separate thread.

The solution appears to be to use Control.Invoke, however, I have too many UI actions to perform, so I am concerned that perhaps I'm not taking the right path.

Which of the following should I do?

- Option A: Stick with **Invoke** anyway, and perform each of the actions on each of the various controls using Invoke for each of them.
- Option B: Put a 50ms repeating timer, where every 50ms, I check if a boolean **DataReceived == true**, and if so, update the UI controls accordingly. (with DataReceived set to true every time I read data in the Serial Port DataReceivedEventHandler, and otherwise false.)
- Option C: Any other option?

**UPDATE:**

Success with the following (based on @tcarvin's Answer and @Hans Passant's comment).

```
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   if (this.InvokeRequired())
   {
      this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler<SerialDataReceivedEventArgs>(DataReceivedHandler), new object[] { sender, e });
      return;
   }

   tbSerialStatus.Text = "Received text";    
}
```

Comment: Just make an effort to buffer the data you receive.  There isn't much point in invoking very often, you only need to keep human eyes happy.  Doing it often is problematic anyway, it can cause a firehose problem where the UI thread gets too many invoke requests and stops painting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are over thinking this.  Assuming you are coding within a form, something like this should work.  This is from the hip, you might need to tweak it a bit:

```
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{

   if (this.InvokeRequired)
   {
      this.Invoke(new EventHandler<SerialDataReceivedEventArgs>(DataReceivedHandler), sender, e);
      return;
   }

   // everything here runs on the UI thread, do what you like, 
   // and update as many UI controls as you like.

}
```

As you can see, you don't have to wrap each control access in a separate `Control.Invoke`.

Comment: Ah, so each control doesn't need to be separately invoked! But why is it `Control.Invoke`, shouldn't it be `this.Invoke`? Also, why did you assign the `DataReceivedHandler` as the delegate -- we are already in that handler, so shouldn't the goal be to go to a method on the UI thread instead? I know you just wrote this as a draft, but I'm trying to make sure.

Comment: This is a troublesome answer.  Don't use Control.BeginInvoke like that.  It is a property, not a method, it is always going to be *true*.  And *never* use Control.Invoke(), it is a major source of deadlock.  Especially in a DataReceived event handler, calling the SerialPort.Close() method on the UI thread at program exit has very high odds to deadlock.  Always use BeginInvoke() instead.

Comment: Problem solved - thank you both! (See UPDATE with the working code on my Question.)

Comment: @HansPassant, You mean, don't use InvokeRequired like that right?  Sorry, it was just from memory, I do both VB.NET and C# and am always doing typos like that.  My point was to show that you Control.Invoke (or BeginInvoke) once and you can act upon all the controls you want once you are on the UI thread.

Comment: @boardbite It is worth mentioning that a more robust solution would accumulate the serial reads into a byte buffer that is inspected on each event, and only once a complete message / frame is received, then you would remove that from the buffer and send it to the UI via an Invoke or BeginInvoke.

Comment: @tcarvin: Got you; thanks. I have set up a condition for reading until end-of-line.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. This approach works:

```
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   if (this.InvokeRequired())
   {
      this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler<SerialDataReceivedEventArgs>(DataReceivedHandler), new object[] { sender, e });
      return;
   }

   tbSerialStatus.Text = "Received text";    
}
```